# Is it possible to get a Russian visa with a Dutch passport while holding the Russian nationality?

Tags: visas, russia, netherlands, dual-nationality

In a discussion with travel buddies the following issue came up as the result of a Russian trip planning.

The situation of the person is as follows:

- Born in Azerbeidjan (former Soviet state).
- In the possession of a Dutch passport.
- Due to being born in a former Soviet state he is also registered as having the Russian nationality (I found this causality weird, but that's how it was explained). He doesn't have a valid Russian passport though.
- In the Dutch passport it's obviously stated that he is born in Azerbeidjan.
- For some reason (the person was not really clear about this) obtaining a Russian passport is not an easy option. He said it involves a large amount of money, a lot of time and hassle.

Is it possible for this person to obtain a Russian visa in The Netherlands on his Dutch passport?

The story goes that this is not possible as the Russians will note the country of birth and then conclude that the person needs to be in possession of a Russian passport, hence denying access on another (in this case Dutch) passport.
I could not find any hard facts supporting this story, that's why I decided to ask this question here.

Comment: If he has the Russian nationality, (why) gan't he get a Russian passport?

Comment: Yes, that was my first reaction too. I'm not sure, he said it was difficult involving a considerable amount of money. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: It is now a lot easier to renew an expired passport in New York consulate than before, however still takes a lot of time and paperwork. I was told too officially you can't get a visa if you are Russian citizen. Another option is to give up your citizenship.

Comment: @Vitalik This sounds a bit like what the guy was telling me. He was against the plan of getting a Russian passport, so could you please elaborate on the other option(s) in an answer? Do you have some source, preferably online, that forbids issuing a visa to Russian citizens on a non-Russian passport?

Comment: My only source is a phone conversation i had with the Russian Consulate a couple of years ago.

Comment: I was under the impression that Dutch have anti-double nationality laws, thus you cannot legally have Dutch and any other nationality (except very short list of circumstances).

Comment: @vartec I have found similar information, but the laws regarding double nationality have changed considerably in the past 10 years. I'm not sure how long my buddy has the Dutch nationality and under what circumstances he acquired it, so I can't really say if his actions are legal. I think jpatokal's answer covers it mostly, but I'm waiting to see if Vitalik decides to elaborate on the process of renewing a Russian passport for this purpose.

Comment: To renew your passport first the consulate obtains a proof that the person is a russian citizen. That is they check that you lived in Russia in Feb 1992 i think. Then you apply for passport renewal. It takes probably at least 6 months in NYC and cost less than $200 these days. IN the past it was a lot more expensive and there were fines for not being registered with the consulate.

Comment: @vartec I don't think there is any general ban on double nationality in the Netherlands (there was a project, though). People have to give up other nationalities if they are naturalized (as opposed to being born Dutch or becoming Dutch through “optie”) but there are exceptions, e.g. if you lived at least five years in the Netherlands as a child, if you can't renounce your other nationality or if you are married to a Dutch person. The list of exceptions is not very long but it does cover many people. At least I know some and I read that there are 1-2M people with double nationality.

Comment: @Annoyed: actually it also affects natural born Dutch if they go live abroad and obtain other nationality, they must give up Dutch nationality. Anyway, *general rule* is no double nationality, you're right that there are some exceptions.

Comment: @vartec But people who have a Dutch parent can have two nationalities and that's not an exception to anything (quite the opposite, losing your nationality because you took up another one is an exception to the rule that you are Dutch if you have a Dutch parent). It's a matter of interpretation but that's not quite how a general rule would work (by contrast, some countries do have such rules on the books).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend seems to be out of luck.  The Russian Consulate in San Francisco [states quite clearly](http://www.consulrussia.org/eng/rules.html#5) that former citizens of the USSR or successor states need to prove they are no longer Russian citizens:

> **Former USSR and Russian citizens**
>
> Applicants who used to be citizens of
>   the USSR or of the Russian Federation and then emigrated from the USSR
>   or from Russia must submit: one of the documents which confirms that
>   they are no longer citizens of the Russian Federation (so called "Visa
>   to Israel" or stamp in their passport saying that they left for
>   "permanent residence abroad" before the 6th of February, 1992 or
>   official document certifying that their Russian citizenship was
>   abrogated), otherwise the applications will not be accepted.

And in [the FAQ](http://www.consulrussia.org/eng/faq.html):

> **13. Although my passport says that I was born in the Soviet Union (USSR) or Russia, I knowfor sure that I am not a Russian citizen, but
>   all the documents which confirm this fact got lost long time ago. What
>   do I do?**
>
> You can send a special request for confirmation of the absence of
>   Russian citizenship to the Russian authorities through the Consulate.
>   It takes time (approximately 1-6 month), so, please apply in advance.
>   Upon receiving the answer, the Consulate will issue you official
>   document confirming that you are no longer a Russian citizen.

So they will need to either apply for Russian citizenship (and probably lose Dutch citizenship in the process, so not necessarily a good move...) or formally renounce their Russian citizenship.

Comment: sounds like that person already has Russian citizenship so no need to apply for it. It really sounds it's easier just to renew the passport even if it takes a lot of time and paperwork.

Answer (score 3):

For what I understand 'Russian nationality' means Russian ethnicity here (a common confusion, национальность in Russian should be translated as 'ethnicity' rather than 'nationality'), so it doesn't really give him any preferences, unless he wants to get Russian citizenship, which is also not easy.

That other answer is unrelated to him because he never held Russian or Soviet citizenship.